# Where can one graph portfolio performance over time?

Tags: united-states, stocks, stock-analysis

I'm used to my employer provided 401k website, which allows me to see a "personal rate of return" over a specified time period, plotted on a line chart.  It also allows me to see individual stocks and their value over time on a line chart.  Both allow viewing by percentage gain or dollar value, based on my purchase dates and amounts.

TD Ameritrade does not provide this, leading me to consider leaving for other brokerages.  I was very surprised to find out that their competitors also do not provide this (we now have accounts with Schwab and Fidelity, neither of which are much better than TDA).  This seems like essential functionality for long term investing, or at least for making long term investing fun enough to take part in, which leads me to believe it must be available elsewhere as a third party service.  However, I've not been able to find anything.  Google Finance offers a very basic chart, showing only whole portfolio performance and only by dollar amount in pre-set time increments, but it doesn't appear to work correctly as it shows losses where there were not any.

Is there a free service that allows you to enter your portfolio, along with trade dates and amounts, and then graphs your personal rate of return in real time?

Comment: Vectorvest does but it is not free.

Comment: Not free, not realtime, but I'm using Quicken to track my finances including my funds, and it can display various statistics as of the last update, including downloading current (somewhat delayed) share values from the net.

Comment: Hopefully you find a free solution to your liking. But if not... Google Docs has the GOOGLEFINANCE function (https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281) that allows you to get date-specific quotes which you can use in a spreadsheet. Good luck!

Comment: A late comment, but I really like Sigfig.  I too have a TD Ameritrade account and was able to link to it through Sigfig and see my daily balance going back over a year.  It's also nice in that it shows your portfolio (account) performance against benchmark indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just started using Personal Capital (www.personalcapital.com) after seeing the recommendation at several places.  I believe it gives you what you want to see, but I don't think you can back populate it with old information.   So if you log in and link accounts today, you'll have it going forward.

I only put in my investment accounts as I use another tool to track my day-to-day spending.   I use Personal Capital to track my investment returns over time.  How did my portfolio compare to S&P 500, etc.

[image: Screen shot]

And here is a shot of the "You Index" which I think is close to what you are looking for:

[image: you index chart]

Comment: I have been using Personal Capital for the last 4 months. Coming from Mint, Personal Capital is much better for tracking net worth, portfolio performance, and the performance of individual investments. I have had very few problems setting up my accounts. The Android app works well too. I can't recommend it enough.

Answer (score 0):

I use Yahoo Finance to plot my portfolio value over time. Yahoo Finance uses SigFig to link accounts (I've linked to Fidelity), which then allows you to see you exact portfolio and see a plot of its historical value. I'm not sure what other websites SigFig will allow you to sync with, but it is worth a try. Here is what the plot I have looks like, although this is slightly out of date, but still gives you an idea of what to expect.

[image: Screenshot of the plot generated by Yahoo Finance]

Comment: May be useful, but giving your broker account and password to a third party takes a LOT of trust. And even if you do trust them, you may be violating the broker's term of service by handing out your password.